# RandomizedSearchCV not accepting values in the parameters dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't get RandomizedSearchCv to accept the parameter dictionary without giving errors for the last parameter in the parameter grid.

```
def build_model(n_hidden=1, n_neurons=30, learning_rate=3e-3, input_shape=[8]):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
    for layer in range(n_hidden):
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_neurons, activation="relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

import scikeras
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
keras_reg = KerasRegressor(build_model())
```

**Error**

```
from scipy.stats import reciprocal
param_distribs = {
    "n_hidden": (0,1,2,3),
    "n_neurons": np.arange(1,100),
    "learning_rate": reciprocal(0.001,0.01)
}

from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
rnd_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_reg, param_distribs, n_iter=10, cv=3, verbose=2)
rnd_search_cv.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100,
                    validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid),
                    callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])
```

*ValueError: Invalid parameter learning_rate for estimator KerasRegressor.
This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasRegressor constructor:
`KerasRegressor(learning_rate=0.0038900563923488303)`
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`*

**Works**

```
from scipy.stats import reciprocal
param_distribs = {
    # "n_hidden": (0,1,2,3),
    # "n_neurons": np.arange(1,100),
    # "learning_rate": reciprocal(0.001,0.01)
}

from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
rnd_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_reg, param_distribs, n_iter=10, cv=3, verbose=2)
rnd_search_cv.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100,
                    validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid),
                    callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])
```

I've changing the datatypes of the parameter grid but nothing seems to work. I also tried setting the parameter to the value the error suggest and no luck.

This code works for many others in my course.

Comment: What is your version of `scikeras` and `sklearn`? Also, how are you importing `keras`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably  `"learning_rate": reciprocal(0.001,0.01)`. Not sure what it is. Maybe just try `(0.001,0.005, 0.01)`?

Comment: Same error. Even if you take out the learning_rate, the error falls on the last parameter (n_neurons whne learning_rate is removed).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with 'scikeras', but it seems the following is a step in the right direction:

```
def build_model(n_hidden=1, n_neurons=30, learning_rate=3e-3, input_shape=[8]):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape))
    for layer in range(n_hidden):
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_neurons, activation="relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

import scikeras
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
keras_reg = KerasRegressor(build_model, n_hidden=1, n_neurons=30, learning_rate=3e-3, input_shape=[8])
```